# Hsqldb support GEOMETRY column?

Tags: java, geometry, hsqldb

I have tried junit with hsqldb(v2.2.6),but it doesn't seem to support geometry.

Here is my code and error info:

java:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
@Column(columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
public Point getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}
```

errors:

```
DEBUG - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@126f816 handling a throwable.
   java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: MDSYS
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:64)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:204)
```

How do I handle it ?

Comment: Well, for starters it is telling you that the MDSYS schema is NOT present in the database. So it didn't even get to the point where it could tell you if the type is not supported

Answer (score 2):

`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` is an Oracle type if I'm not mistaken. So that won't work with HSQLDB.

The manual does not list a geometry type: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#N103C9

So I guess your only option is to file an enhancement request.